# Pulling Laravel project from GitHub will not connect to DB

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, mysql-workbench

PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

This is the error that my team has not been able to solve. Each member is unable to pull the laravel project and connect to the database. We have tried using Windows 10 with XAMPP and restarted the project on Mac but every person has had the same issue.

We have done through the instructions of cloning a project from GitHub to include naming the DB homestead and using no password (not ideal to not be able to use correct DB names if working on multiple projects)

Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/vsestudios242/SPRING.git

Here is the .env DB portion:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Here is the database.php

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

We have followed the following instructions:
https://gist.github.com/hootlex/da59b91c628a6688ceb1

The expected behavior is that, on Mac, each Laravel project should be able to connect to a named MySQL DB and by using migrations and seeds the DB should be able to interact with data.

SOLUTION FOUND: So the workaround I had to do was to download squelPro which allows me to create the database. However, it crashes every time i access the db with its GUI. I am able to then interact with the DB using MySQL Workbench. Creating a new db in workbench is the issue and I am not sure of the cause just the that the workaround works.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? I would love to know the actual issue instead of using a workaround.

Comment: Don't name the *DB* homestead, name the *database user* that.

Comment: Ditch those instructions and follow the official ones, too. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#connecting-to-databases

Comment: we created the DB using Homestead and password Secret but still get the same result

Comment: i've seen your updates. I notice that you put `sltw-master` on database.php but you also have DB_DATABASE on your .env it still read homestead becuase the 2nd parameter in env() function will only be read if it is not existing on .env since you have DB_DATABASE on your `.env` it will read its value

Comment: Your Homestead box, per the docs I linked, **already has a user** and password, `homestead` and `secret`. Capitalization matters, and you shouldn't be creating a user, you should be using the one that's already there.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Answer (score 0):

after you pull from the github and you don't have a `.env` files on your server. you should create one or copy the env.example that comes from the github.

after that change your `.env` base on your database credentials. after saving don't forget to run this artisan command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: We have tried this on the .env but still have the same issue

Comment: you should put the credentials on `.env` then run `php artisan config:clear` after updating the `.env` on your error you still have homestead as db name

Comment: with the same error using the homestead credentials?

Comment: how about running `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: no matter what I try it gives the same issue. I think its related to SQL not laravel

Comment: so your mysql user name is homestead? try to run it. `mysql -u homestead -p`

Comment: but if you try to `mysql -u root -p` ??

Comment: that hasn't worked. I created a fresh laravel project and it still is giving the same issue

Comment: yup i think its your mysql issue